Tkinter - trace_add() not executing the validation method
Tkinter menu executes New_Debtor_Acc in another module. New_Debtor_Acc is also use tkinter. The label has a trace_add() to validate data entered interactively. But it will not execute, using the normal "def New_Debtor_Acc".
I did however found that when I insert a duplicate call to it, without the "def", that the validation is executed. Obviously the method is now called during initialization before the main menu start up.
Below are the 2 modules>
# start.py
# ========

# Import functions
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from accdeb import New_Debtor_Acc

# Create main menu
class MenuApp(Tk):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('1048x640+100+100')
        self.title('A2B')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # Create menubar
        menubar = Menu(self)
        dashboardmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        accountsmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        exitmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        # Add Dashboard Menu and commands
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Dashboard', menu=dashboardmenu)
        dashboardmenu.add_command(label="Main Dashboard", command=self.DoNothing)
        dashboardmenu.add_command(label="Unallocated Freight", command=self.DoNothing)

        # Add Accounts Menu and commands
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Accounts', menu=accountsmenu)
        accountsmenu.add_command(label="General Ledger", command=self.DoNothing)
        accountsmenu.add_cascade(label='Debtors', command=New_Debtor_Acc)  # New Debtor
        accountsmenu.add_command(label="Creditors", command=self.DoNothing)
        accountsmenu.add_command(label="Stock", command=self.DoNothing)

        # Add Exit Menu and commands
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Exit', menu=exitmenu)
        exitmenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.destroy)

        # Display Menu
        (self.config(menu=menubar))

    # Do nothing button used while program is still in development
    def DoNothing(self):
        win = NothingApp(self)

# While program is still in development, use this nothing window
class NothingApp(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.geometry('300x100+200+200')
        self.title('Do Nothing')
        #  To allow the nothing window to receive events and prevent
        #  users from interacting with the main window
        self.grab_set()

        Button(self, text='Close',
               command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)

# Main menu
def main_menu():
    mnu = MenuApp()

    # Run main loop
    mnu.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Main menu
    main_menu()


# accdeb.py
# =========

# Import functions
import tkinter as tk

# Debtor App
class DebtorApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, hdr_desc: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.grab_set()  # Disable main menu
        self.geometry('600x640+150+150')
        self.title(hdr_desc + ' Debtor Account')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.ent1_deb_mst_nrVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.ent1_deb_mst_nrVar.trace_add("write", self.validate_deb_mst_nr)
        self.lblZ_deb_msgVar = tk.StringVar()

        # Status frame
        status_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        status_frame.pack()

        padding = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

        # Status message
        status_frame.lblY_deb_msg = tk.Label(status_frame, text="Status : ", **padding)
        status_frame.lblY_deb_msg.pack(side='left')
        status_frame.lblZ_deb_msg = tk.Label(status_frame, textvariable=self.lblZ_deb_msgVar,
                                             text="None", foreground='red', **padding)
        status_frame.lblZ_deb_msg.pack(side='left')

        # Body frame
        body_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        body_frame.pack()

        # Configure the grid
        body_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
        body_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)

        # Debtor master account nr
        body_frame.lbl1_deb_mst_nr = tk.Label(body_frame,
                                              text="Debtor master account number  [AAAA0000]")
        body_frame.lbl1_deb_mst_nr.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **padding)
        self.cmd_deb_mst_nr = (body_frame.register(self.validate_deb_mst_nr), '%P')
        body_frame.ent1_deb_mst_nr = tk.Entry(body_frame, width=12,
                                              textvariable=self.ent1_deb_mst_nrVar)
        body_frame.ent1_deb_mst_nr.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.E, **padding)
        body_frame.ent1_deb_mst_nr.focus_set()

        # Button frame
        button_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        button_frame.pack()

        # Close button
        button_frame.btn1_close = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Close', command=self.destroy)
        button_frame.btn1_close.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.E, **padding)

    def validate_deb_mst_nr(self, *args):
        input_deb_mst_nr = self.ent1_deb_mst_nrVar.get().upper()
        error_msg = valid_deb_mst(input_deb_mst_nr)
        self.ent1_deb_mst_nrVar.set(input_deb_mst_nr)
        self.lblZ_deb_msgVar.set(error_msg)

# Validate Deb Master Number
def valid_deb_mst(input_chrs):
    # Allowed input format: [AAAA0000]
    allowed_chrs = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    allowed_nums = '1234567890'
    format_mess = 'Format is  [AAAA0000]'
    length_chrs = len(input_chrs)
    # Check position 1 to 4 for alphabetic characters
    if (length_chrs > 0) and (length_chrs <= 4):
        copy_chrs = input_chrs[0:4-1]
        valid_chars = all(c in allowed_chrs for c in copy_chrs)
        if not valid_chars:
            error_mess = "".join([format_mess, '\n', "Input should be Alphabetic  [AAAA..."])
        else:
            error_mess = ""
    # Check position 5 to 8 for numeric characters
    elif (length_chrs >= 5) and (length_chrs <= 8):
        copy_chrs = input_chrs[5-1:8]  # [5-1:8-1] Somehow miss to pick up char on position 8
        valid_chars = all(c in allowed_nums for c in copy_chrs)
        if not valid_chars:
            error_mess = "".join([format_mess, '\n', "Input should be Numeric  ...0000]"])
        else:
            error_mess = ""
    # Check length max 8 characters
    elif length_chrs > 8:
        error_mess = "".join([format_mess, '\n', "Too many characters entered"])
    # All OK
    else:
        error_mess = ""
    return error_mess

# New Debtor
def New_Debtor_Acc():
    deb = DebtorApp('New')

# 1. When New_Debtor_Acc below is NOT run:
#      The validation via trace_add("write", self.validate_deb_mst_nr) is NOT run
# 2. When New_Debtor_Acc below IS run:
#      The validation via trace_add("write", self.validate_deb_mst_nr) IS run
#      It obviously also run on program initialisation...
#    What am I doing wrong?
#
# New_Debtor_Acc()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise RuntimeError("accdeb.py: This module may NOT run as main.")


You are creating multiple instances of Tk - one in each file.  Each of these is an entirely independent GUI environment - in particular, Vars created in one environment cannot be used at all from a different environment.  You need to use Toplevel instead as the base class for additional windows, so that everything is in a single environment.

The problem is likely related to the fact that you're creating more than one instance of Tk. Variables that exist in one instance are not available in the other instance. When you use tk.Toplevel as the base class for MenuApp the problem goes away.
